# How to draw a video frame from PyRealSense2 on a PyGame canvas?

Tags: python, pygame, realsense

After initializing PyGame with

```
flags = pygame.FULLSCREEN | pygame.NOFRAME | pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.HWSURFACE
width = 0
height = 0  # fullscreeen

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( ( width, height ), flags )
```

I get the color frame from the RealSense camera with

```
frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
colorFrame = frames.get_color_frame()
```

But how can this frame be drawn on screen?

Answer (score 0):

```
# create a new Surface from the frame's data
image = pygame.image.frombuffer(colorFrame.data, ( colorFrame.width, colorFrame.height ), 'RGB')

# copy data on screen at position (0, 0)
screen.blit(image, ( 0, 0 ))
```